# Importar relaciones BD MYSQL

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, phpmyadmin

Tengo una duda, realice unas relaciones internas, por diseñador de una BD  este es el resultado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo realice  un export de la BD y lo instale en otro Equipo, y aunque la BD de datos esta bien, no existen relaciones ... a que se debe? y como debo solucionarlo:

Así queda la BD cuando la Importo en otro Equipo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En tu exportación deberias poder ver algo como **ForeignKey**.

Haz la exportación nuevamente y busca si tiene algo como te he dicho.

**Algo así**

```
CREATE TABLE Orders (
OrderID int NOT NULL,
OrderNumber int NOT NULL,
PersonID int,
PRIMARY KEY (OrderID),
FOREIGN KEY (PersonID) REFERENCES Persons(PersonID)
```

);